# Installing multiple versions of ant on same machine

Tags: java, ant, java-8, java-7

I want to run different projects one of which runs on Java8 and another on Java7. I have installed latest ant version 1.10 on my mac. If I set `JAVA_HOME` to java7 then ant execution fails with

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

(Ant 1.9 runs on Java7)

Comment: Look into jenv or point to the exact location.

Comment: I would suggest evaluating the sdkman tool. It enables you to install multiple versions of Java and ANT. See: http://sdkman.io/  Another legitmate option is to install virtualization software like virualbox to run builds within a virtual machine and finally there's always Docker

Answer (score 4):

According to Ant's [home page](http://ant.apache.org/):

> The Apache Ant team currently maintains two lines of development. The 1.9.x releases require Java5 at runtime and 1.10.x requires Java8 at runtime.

So you need to set JAVA_HOME to a JDK 8 in order to run Ant 1.10. But this is just to run Ant itself, this has nothing to do with your projects. In other words, there is no need to use multiple versions of Ant to compile two projects that use two different Java versions. Ant 1.10.x can be used for both projects. You control the Java version from within the tasks in the build files. For example, the [`javac`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task supports compiling using different JDK versions:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
     destdir="${build}"
     classpath="xyz.jar"
     debug="on"
     source="1.4"
/>
```